# Как через xml задать свой шрифт для элементов?

Tags: android, android-xml

У меня в директории assets/fonts/ есть шрифт georgia.ttf, как можно его установить для кнопок, текстовых полей, текстбоксов и др. через разметку activity_main.xml?

Comment: программным способом: создать TypeFace и закинуть его в View setTextTypeFace

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular />
```